# Impute missing values in subset of mixed-type DataFrame using a mask

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code to create two pandas DataFrames `a` and `b`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['X', 1, np.nan, 3],
        ['X', 4, 5, 6],
        ['Y', 7, 8, 9]
    ],
    columns = ["Group", "A", "B", "C"]
)

b = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['X', 1, 2, 3],
        ['X', 4, 5, np.nan],
        ['X', 7, 8, 9]
    ],
    columns = ["Group", "A", "B", "C"]
)
```

I would like to replace any `NaN` values in columns `["A", "B", "C"]` if the location is `NaN` in either DataFrame. That is, I would like to use the following mask:

```
missing_vals = pd.isnull(a) | pd.isnull(b)
print(missing_vals)
#   Group      A      B      C
#0  False  False   True  False
#1  False  False  False   True
#2  False  False  False  False
```

I tried:

```
replacement_value = -1
a[missing_vals] = replacement_value
```

but that resulted in:

> `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

I've also tried accessing just the desired columns using `a[missing_vals.loc[:, ["A", "B", "C"]]]` but produced an error as well.

The desired outputs are:

```
print(a)
#  Group  A   B   C
#0     X  1  -1   3
#1     X  4   5  -1
#2     Y  7   8   9

print(b)
#  Group  A   B   C
#0     X  1  -1   3
#1     X  4   5  -1
#2     X  7   8   9
```

Notice that rows `0` and `1`/columns `"B"` and `"C"` have been replaced with the `replacement_value` in both DataFrames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using mask

```
s=(a.isnull())|(b.isnull())
s
Out[297]: 
   Group      A      B      C
0  False  False   True  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False

a.mask(s,-1)
Out[299]: 
  Group  A    B  C
0     X  1 -1.0  3
1     X  4  5.0 -1
2     Y  7  8.0  9
b.mask(s,-1)
Out[300]: 
  Group  A  B    C
0     X  1 -1  3.0
1     X  4  5 -1.0
2     X  7  8  9.0
```

Comment: Thanks! `a.mask(missing_vals, -1)` also works in my case.

Comment: @pault yep~ :-) just too lazy to type full name of parameter :-)

Comment: Don't forget `a.where(~s, -1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha yep :-) that is it

Answer (score 2):

`np.where`

```
m = a.isnull() | b.isnull()
pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, -1, a), columns=a.columns)

  Group  A   B   C
0     X  1  -1   3
1     X  4   5  -1
2     Y  7   8   9
```